# импорт структуры и метода из c++

Tags: c#, c++

есть такая структура

```
struct VkExtensionProperties {
    char        extensionName[VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t    specVersion;
}
```

и метод в котором она используется

`VkResult vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(const char* pLayerName, uint32_t* pPropertyCount, VkExtensionProperties* pProperties)`

в c# написал так

```
public unsafe struct VkExtensionProperties
{
    public fixed char extensionName[(int)vk.VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE];
    public uint specVersion;
}

VkResult vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pLayerName, ref uint pPropertyCount,[Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] VkExtensionProperties[] vkExtensionProperties);
```

но структуры оказываются пустыми. как правильно импортировать структуру и метод?

Comment: Что значит импортировать? Использовать в с#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char в С# означает совсем не то, что в С++. Вместо массива char в данном случае нужно использовать string и ByValTStr.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct VkExtensionProperties
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=(int)vk.VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE)]
    public string extensionName;
    public uint specVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить в структуру  оператор

```
VkExtensionProperties*
operator ()(const char* p,  uint32_t k)
{
    if (p)
        strcpy(extensionName, p);
    specVersion = k;
    return this;
}
```

а потом можно будет передавать в вашу функцию например так:

```
const char* name = "pLayerName";
uint32_t  k{5};
VkExtensionProperties v;
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(name, &k, v(name, k));
```

поля обьекта `v` будут иннициализированы первым и вторым аргументом